# Webscraping Videostream-Urls not working properly

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, htmlunit

So I am trying to scrape video-urls from Streaminghosters like StreamCloud.eu , Streamango.com and so on. The problem is: when inspecting the website manually, we can scrape the video-source URL pretty easy from the "src"-attribute: see this
[image]

Though when scraping with Java-HtmlUnit or Python, I receive this:
[image]

As you can see on the second picture, the src-attribute isn't loaded and I have ran into this problem a few times now. JavaScript is enabled and I have tried around a lot, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the reason. It is because some Video-Players use flash. HtmlUnit does not support flash, so the player is not loaded of course.

Thanks though.